# Springboot loading wrong config despite being explicit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have the following Configuration classes, one in the main package and one in the test package.

#### Main

```
@Configuration
public class DynamoConfiguration {
```

#### Test

```
@TestConfiguration
public class DynamoTestConfiguration {
```

#### Unit Test

```java
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DynamoTestConfiguration.class})
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
public class DynamoClientTest {
```

Yet, it's still loading `DynamoConfiguration` and causing failures when I only want the `DynamoTestConfiguration` to be loaded. How can I ensure that happens?

Comment: Look for @TestConfiguration, it might help you

Comment: Sorry typo, but I am already using TestConfiguration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `@SpringBootTest`, then your application is started, along with any `@Configuration` classes on the classpath. Spring has no idea that `DynamoConfiguration` is special and you don't want to load it.

As a way around this, you can use profiles:

```
@Profile("prod")
@Configuration
public class DynamoConfiguration {
```

and in your test, add `!prod` to your `@ActiveProfiles`:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "!prod,test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DynamoTestConfiguration.class})
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
public class DynamoClientTest {
```

This should avoid that `DynamoConfiguration` gets loaded in the test.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping there was another way than hardcoding profile names in my tests, but it seems like the answer is no. Was hoping to say like "scan for all testconfigurations only" sorta thing

Comment: Come to think of it, you don't _need_ to state `!prod` in the test itself since `prod` is not active by default anyway normally.